# Angular: Injecting NgControl While Monitoring Changes

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Given I have a directive that injects `NgControl`:

```
export class MyFormDirective {
  constructor(@Self() private ngControl: NgControl) {
    this.ngControl.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
     // Do stuff
    });
  }
```

Used like so:

```html
<input type="text" [formControl]="sampleControl" appMyFormDirective />
```

Is there a way for me to handle the situation where `sampleControl` is updated?

```
this.sampleControl = new FormControl(); // this will break the directive subscription
```

I have a component that potentially has multiple forms bound to it over its lifetime, which stops my directive from working.  I can force everything to re-render by using `*ngFor` over `*ngIf`, but since the form directives themselves seem to be handling the change ok, I'd rather just fix the issue in my directive if possible.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Do you want to update the control as the user is typing? If not when do you want to update the control?

Comment: Angular will add classes to indicate the state of the control (valid, touched, etc): one thing this directive does is something similar to indicate if the control has a value or not, which is why it subscribes to the valueChanges.  If a new control is bound, I need to subscribe to the new control's changes for this to work

Answer (score 1):

Since I couldn't find any better solution, here is what worked for me:

I've added an input to my directive:

```
@Input()
formControl?: AbstractControl;
```

and implemented `OnChanges` interface. This way if when the `formControl` reference is updated, the `ngOnChanges` callback is triggered and I can react to it.

I couldn't find any way to handle it by just using the injected `ngControl`.

Another approach (perhaps even better) is to implement [DoCheck](https://angular.io/api/core/DoCheck) interface and use it like this:

```
  formControl: AbstractControl|null = null; // class field

  ngDoCheck(): void {
    if (this.formControl !== this.ngControl.control) {
      this.formControl = this.ngControl.control;
      this.doStuff();
    }
  }
```